# Get Video-Duration with avconv via Python

Tags: python, django, shell, video, duration

I need to get the duration of an Video for an application for Django. So I'll have to do this in python. But I'm really a beginner in this. So it would be nice, if you can help.

This is what I got so far:

```
import subprocess
task = subprocess.Popen("avconv -i video.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed -r 's/([^\.]*)\..*/\1/'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time = task.communicate()[0]
print time
```

I want to solve it with avconv because I'm allready using this at another point. The shell-command works well so far and gives me an output like:
HH:MM:SS.

But when I'm executing the python-code I just get an non-interpretable symbol on the shell.

Thanks a lot allready for your help!

Found a solution. Problem was the sed-part:

```
import os
import subprocess

task = subprocess.Popen("avconv -i video.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed -e 's/.\{4\}$//'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time = task.communicate()[0]
print time
```

Because it is allways the same part, it was enought to just cut the last 4 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python documentation:

> Warning
>
> Use [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) rather than [`.stdin.write`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin), [`.stdout.read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) or [`.stderr.read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr) to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

So you should really user `communicate` for that:

```
import subprocess
task = subprocess.Popen("avconv -i video.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed -r 's/([^\.]*)\..*/\1/'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time = task.communicate()[0]
print time
```

That way you can also catch stderr message, if any.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it also in the Post above, but it still gives me an cryptic looking output ...

Comment: And if the video doesn't exist it should give an error-output, but instead there is just nothing as output ...

Comment: `communicate` will return 2-elements tuple, on index 0 is stdout, on 1: stderror, so any errors will be on `task.communicate()[1]`.

Comment: Now I see, you're redirecting all stderr into stdout, and then filtering for data that you're looking for. In that case, you won't have any error message, because it's getting filtered by grep.

Comment: You propably shouldn't filter in in command line, but inside python. That will give you more flexibility and ability to handle more data, also to distinguish error messages.

Comment: Thanks, yes [1] gives me None.
Tried it without some of the Pipes, and the problem is the SED-part ...

Comment: Okay, I'll try this. But so far I found a solution (added in first post ... I just changed the sed-part and now it works, but thanks a lot!