# get video duration in django

Tags: django, video, django-views

i would like to get video duration of video stored in database using django i have all video information title url pk

```
 def post(self, request,pk):
    instance = Video.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES,instance=instance)
    video_type = str(self.request.FILES.dict()["file"])[-4:]
    if instance.section.course.teacher.user == request.user and form.is_valid() and video_type == ".mp4":
        video_section = form.save()
        data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': video_section.file.name , 'url': video_section.file.url,"pk":video_section.pk}
    else:
        data = {'is_valid': False}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294988/get-video-duration-with-avconv-via-python

Comment: hi thank's for the reply i have a question does this affect the server performance ?

Comment: I'm not sure with this