# How to calculate video length and Thumbnail of video in django

Tags: django

I doing django project. I'm trying to calculate length of upload video and tring to create Thumbnail of the video. How to do this.

models.py

```
class Video(models.Model):
    video_format = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    video_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    video_size = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    video_duration = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default= datetime.now(), blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    thumbline = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video = request.FILES.get('video')
        video_file = FileSystemStorage()
        file_upload = Video(video_file= video_file.save(video.name, video))
        file_upload.save()
        return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

Comment: check this link [Get video duration in pyhton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844430/how-to-get-the-duration-of-a-video-in-python)
and this the other one [Get video duration with avconf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294988/get-video-duration-with-avconv-via-python)

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion is to use [moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/).

For getting a duration you can use `VideoClipFile`

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoClipFile

video = VideoClipFile(<path to your video file or a video file object>)

video.duration  # this will return the length of the video in seconds
```

For getting a thumbnail, you can use `Image` from Pillow

```
from PIL import Image

frame_data = video.get_frame(1)  # 1 means frame at first second

img = Image.fromarray(frame_data, 'RGB')
```

And do whatever you want with the image.

Comment: `video_file= request.FILES.get('video')` `video=VideoClipFile(video_file)` this is correct way to do this, because i'm getting error

Comment: @kumar added that option.